# How to convert a windows batch file into a signle line "cmd /c" command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the batch file below and wish to convert it to a single line **cmd /c** command.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %%I IN ('chcp') DO SET _codepage_=%%I
SET _codepage_=Cp%_codepage_: =%
ECHO %_codepage_%
ENDLOCAL
```

I tried:

```
cmd /c FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %I IN ('chcp') DO @SET _codepage_=%I && @SET _codepage_=Cp%_codepage_: =% && @ECHO %_codepage_%
```

also tried:

```
cmd /v:on /c FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %I IN ('chcp') DO @SET _codepage_=%I && @SET _codepage_=Cp%_codepage_: =% && @ECHO !_codepage_!
```

but neither approach works! Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd /q/c"for /f "tokens=2delims=:." %a in ('chcp')do for %b in (%a)do echo(Cp%b"
```

What did the original code do? split the output of `chcp`, remove the ending dot (I didn't knew it, thank you), storing the value inside a variable to remove a space from it and prefix it with `Cp` and then echo the variable

What does this code do? split the output of `chcp`, remove the ending dot, but instead of using a variable to remove the space, an aditional `for` loop is used over the value from the first loop, and, instead of prefixing the variable, the `Cp` is included in the data echoed.

Comment: Can you explain a little about your answer? It seems I needed to quote my complete command like this: `cmd /v:on /q /c "FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %I IN ('chcp') DO SET _codepage_=%I && SET _codepage_=Cp!_codepage_: =! && ECHO !_codepage_!"`. But I cannot understand your answer, especially the `do echo(Cp%b` part!

Comment: Also it seems that `delims` needs the extra `.` since in German locale `chcp` result is `Aktive Codepage: 850.` [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1337150/2773737)

Comment: @fubar, first time a see the ending dot, thank you. Added how it works.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, although I will also post how I finally did it and the purpose of this script.

Comment: don't you think the `(` is invalid in `echo(Cp%b`? Shouldn't it be `echo Cp%b`?

Comment: @fubar, no, it is not invalid. Have you problems with it?

Comment: It works with `echo(Cp%b` and `echo Cp%b` both! Why do you need the `(` char?

Comment: It this invalid? `cmd /q /c "FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %a IN ('chcp') DO FOR %b IN (%a) DO ECHO Cp%b"`

Comment: @fubar, no, it is not invalid. The `echo(` is just an habit. See [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554) for the full history. In this case, the bracket is not needed

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [MC ND answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674520/1012053). But just for yucks, I created another solution.

```
cmd /v:on /q /c "(for /f "delims=." %a in ('chcp') do for %b in (%a) do set cp=Cp%b) & echo !cp!"
```

Note that for all solutions, you might consider adding the `/D` option to prevent autorun commands from running.

Comment: It took me much time digging inside windows batch files command and I have to admit I was frustrated! Any other solution is welcome, just for the fun of it!

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was missing double quotes around the **cmd** command. This is how I finally did this:

```
cmd /v:on /q /c "FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %I IN ('chcp') DO SET _codepage_=%I && SET _codepage_=Cp!_codepage_: =! && ECHO !_codepage_!"
```

also correct as [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) pointed out above:

```
cmd /q /c "FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %a IN ('chcp') DO FOR %b IN (%a) DO ECHO Cp%b"
```

I use this single command in Java with a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) in order to get the console's codepage and pass it to the process's stdout and stderr streams like this:

```
String encoding = getConsoleEncoding(); // use the above cmd command
BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream(),encoding) );
```

So the result of system commands like e.g. **date /t** will display correctly in Java.

Comment: +1, Instead of adding quotes, you could have escaped `&&` as `^&^&`. Actually, you only need a single `^&`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save above into a file, name it as my.bat.  Then use:

```
cmd.exe /c "call my.bat"
```

For In one command line, not use batch file, you can:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=:." %I IN ('chcp') DO (SET _codepage1_=%I && SET _codepage_=Cp%_codepage1_% && ECHO %_codepage_%)
```

Comment: I do not wish to create a batch file; not even a tmp one. I think it can be done with a single line cmd, but cannot get it right!